# Java GPIO options other that PI4J?

Tags: gpio, java

What are the options other than PI4J on Java?

I looking as lack of response them.

I have 3 Tickets open one this Java one with Vaadin and one with PI4J trying to find out why I get a core dump.

Java says Vaadin is the problem.

Vaadin says Java is the problem.

PI4J does not respond in over 20 days

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

The only other option I am aware of is https://github.com/nkolban/jpigpio which is an interface to my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

Comment: Does it have interrupts? Does it work OK with Tomcat 8?

Comment: I'm not a Java person and have no idea about Tomcat.  pigpio has callbacks.  Linux handles interrupts.

Comment: Do you have a example for Java?

Comment: @KevinRoberts Sorry, as I say I'm not a Java user.  You could try contacting the author.

Comment: Looks like its a dead project Neil said: "I'm afraid I haven't touched that project in a long, long time ... it does look like there might be samples here:

https://github.com/nkolban/jpigpio/tree/master/JPigpio/src/tests

 But I'm afraid it is "as-is","